# Declare and Define a Function in a Namespace?

Tags: c++

I have the following header:

```
#ifndef MY_H_
#define MY_H_

namespace A {
void f() {
// do something
}
}
#endif
```

However, when I compiled, I got errors like multiple definition of A::f().  I thought that the #ifndef check is enough to avoid duplicate definitions in 1 translation unit.  Maybe I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing the fact that the multiple definition problems appertain to *multiple* translation units, not to 1 translation unit.

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks for your quick response.  Yes, I see what you mean.  I can make it static to avoid the issue.  Inline also works for my compiler.  But because inline is just a hint to the compiler so compiler might ignore it and I will still end up with multiple definitions.  Or compiler is guaranteed not to ignore inline in this case?

Comment: The real answer is not to put definitions in headers. Then you don't get multiple definitions!

Comment: Haha. Right.  Asking compiler to inline is indeed my original intention and so I don't want to have the definition in a separated C++ file.  But I wonder whether inline keyword is guaranteed to be considered in this situation or there is a better/more generic way to handle the situation (besides moving into a cpp file).

Comment: @Hei, that's a far more interesting question. Why not ask that one? I *think* the answer is that if a compiler declines to `inline`, then it reserves the right to export the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`inline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) specifier before the function definition:

```
#ifndef MY_H_
#define MY_H_

namespace A {
inline void f() {
// do something
}
}
#endif
```

Comment: Inline works for my compiler.  But because inline is just a hint to the compiler so compiler might ignore it and I will still end up with multiple definitions.  Or compiler is guaranteed not to ignore inline in this case?

Comment: According to the 1st point in Description at link above: "1) There may be more than one definition of an inline function in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit. For example, an inline function may be defined in a header file that is #include'd in multiple source files." Inline as an optimization hint for compiler is obsolete now.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  So you mean in the new C++ standard (C++11 or C++14), the standard requires the compiler to correctly process inline rather than take inline as a hint?

Comment: In all C++ standards `inline` is just a hint for a compiler. You can omit this specifer when definining member functions inside of class/struct/union.  But `inline` should be used in such cases as yours: to define exactly the same function in different transaltion units.

Comment: Right, I just wonder whether standard enforces it?  If yes, it solves my issue completely.

Comment: Yes, see 7.1.2.4: "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case (3.2). ... If the definition of a function appears in a translation unit before its first declaration as inline, the program is ill-formed. If a function with external linkage is declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared  in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required. ..."

Answer (score 0):

You should declare functions in the header file but define them in your cpp file. If you include this header file from multiple translation units (which is most probable), then there will be multiple implementations available for different translation units. Each of your cpp files that includes this header will have an implementation of `f`. This way, if `f` is to be called, it is ambiguous. By putting the implementation into a cpp file, it can be linked and used that way. But there is only one implementation available which makes it unambiguous.

So, your header file should be:

```
#ifndef MY_H_
#define MY_H_

namespace A
{
    void f(); // declaration only
}

#endif
```

and your source file:

```
#include "myHeader.h"

namespace A
{
    void f()
    {
        // some implementation
    }
}
```

Then, you should be fine. You would usually do that with all of your functions. The only exceptions are `inline` functions/methods or templates but this is beyond the scope of this question.